# "Display math should end with $$" error

Tags: math-mode, errors, listings

I'm trying to write math in a code listing, like so :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin[mathescape]{lstlisting}
$\infty$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error :

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \infty 
l.10 $\infty
            $
?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an argument to `listings` not to `\begin`

```
                  %%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
$\infty$
\end{lstlisting}
```

The reason that you get that error is that TeX allows you to omit the braces around mandatory arguments, and if so takes the first token. so

```
\begin[mathescape]{lstlisting}$\infty$
```

is

```
\begin{[}mathescape]{lstlisting}$\infty$
```

Now `\begin` essentially does `\begingroup\csname[\endcsname` so this is

```
\begingroup\[mathescape]{lstlisting}$\infty$
```

so `\[` starts display math and `mathescape]{lstlisting}` gets typeset as characters in display math mode, then the single `$` is met but TeX wants a double `$$` to end display math so issues a primitive error.

Basically error detection in a macro processing language is usually more by luck than design.

Comment: Thanks ! You must admit the error message wasn't really helpful...

Comment: @otibom actually the reason you get that error is quite funny (if it is not your document:-) I'll put a breakdown in the answer.